# How to make event entry in specific calendar in android programmatically?

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

In my case

I want to provide the choice of the calendar to the user on the starting of my application during the initial login and then the calendar events will enter only to that calendar only, not any other calendar.

#### For example

IF the user having three calendars in his phone 1. google, 2. yahoo, 3.Microsoft.

So on the initial login user able to select which calendar he wants to choose to make calendar events entries.
If he chose yahoo then all events must be entered in yahoo only.

Is that possible to achieve this in android?

I also want to achieve these cases also please help me to achieve these and waiting for answers and thanks in advance

- to fetch global id of the event